# How do I set up Codename One in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I want to use [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/download.html) Java software development tools on Ubuntu with Eclipse. I tried to install Codename One with OpenJDK and Oracle JDK, but it didn't work.

Comment: can you give us some more information? if you try to run it from command line what is the error output?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Codename One doesn't run from the command line. It runs inside Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a regression in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a that broke the simulator/debugger in Codename One, so install the latest version of Eclipse 4.8 instead.

1. Install the latest version of Eclipse.

   ```
   sudo snap install eclipse --classic
   ```

   This command will install the latest Photon Release 4.8 version of Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.
2. In the menu option *Help* -> *Eclipse Marketplace* -> search for *Codename One* -> click the **<kbd>Install</kbd>** button (marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot), and follow the installation process.

   [image]
   <sup>**openjdk-8-jdk should work for the Codename One 5.0 release coming out in September 2018.**</sup>

Comment: The latest plugin should generally work with OpenJDK but that's in beta... To be 100% sure you would need Oracle JDK 8. Notice that OpenJDK should work for the 5.0 release coming out in September 2018.